# Check if result is older than 30 days and add header text above

Tags: php, loops, date

I got a grid with Facebook posts. I want to make an archive that people can open when clicking on a button. When clicked the facebook posts older than 30 days are shown, this needs to be done with ajax but that is for another time. First I need to know how I can seperate the data in my foreach loop.

When the loop reaches the first post that is 30 days or older I want a header text above it showing: 'archive'.

So like this:

```
post
post
post
post

archive
post(30days or older)
post(30days or older)
post(30days or older)
post(30days or older)
```

How can I do this? I already know how old posts are, see my code:

```
foreach ( $feedarray->data as $key => $feed_data )
  {
    if($feed_data->full_picture != ''){
      $fbimage = $feed_data->full_picture;
    }else{
      $fbimage = 'images/placeholder/placeholder.png';
    }

    $shortstrfb = substr($feed_data->message, 0, 70) . '...';
    if($feed_data->message != ''){
      $f++;
    }


    $date1 = date("y-m-d");
    $date2 = date("y-m-d",strtotime($feed_data->updated_time));


    $datetime1 = date_create($date1);
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2);
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    $result = $interval->format('%R%a days');



    // if($f > 5){
    //   break;
    // }

    if($feed_data->message != '' && $feed_data->from->name == 'FB page name'){

      if($result > -30){
        $dagen = 'more than 30';
      }else{
        $dagen = 'less than 30';
      }

      $facebookfeed .= '
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
              <div class="vk-project vk-project-grid-item">
                  <div class="vk-img-frame">
                  <span class="datecorner">'.date("d-m-Y",strtotime($feed_data->updated_time)).''.$dagen.'</span>
                      <a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'" class="vk-img">
                          <img style="width:370px;height:270px;object-fit:cover;" src="'.$fbimage.'" alt="">
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="content-hidden">
                      <p class="inbeeldtext"><a href="'.$feed_data->permalink_url.'">'.$shortstrfb.'</a></p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>';
    }
  }
  echo $facebookfeed;
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can place a variable outside the loop and set it to `true` once the time limit is reached.

By checking against the state of this variable, you can prevent the 'archive' headline from appearing more than once.

```
$reachedArchive = false;

foreach(...) {

    $postUpdated = strtotime($feed_data->updated_time);

    if (!$reachedArchive && $postUpdated <= strtotime('-30 days')) {
        $reachedArchive = true;
        echo '<h2>Archive</h2>';
    }

}
```

Comment: Sometimes this is hard if you respond on a mobile device. ;-) I updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I understand the logic behind your answer but somehow archive is looped multiple times. I can't just add the if statement inside the looped html. So where do I put it?